# Simulating auth in tests for Symfony 4.4 with ZenstruckFoundry

Tags: symfony, authentication, phpunit, symfony-4.4

In Symfony 4.4 I am attempting simulate authenticating a user so that I can write PHPUnit tests for a secured area of my application. I am using the [ZenstruckFoundry](https://symfony.com/doc/current/ZenstruckFoundryBundle/index.html) to create a factory for my User that will be authenticated.

I have also followed the Symfony docs for [Creating an Authentication Token](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/testing/http_authentication.html#creating-the-authentication-token) and originally [opened an issue](https://github.com/zenstruck/foundry/issues/276) in the `zenstruck/foundry` repo. Since this doesn't actually seem to be an issue with Foundry I'm asking here on SO.

My test to an endpoint behind my `main` firewall simply looks like this:

```php
/**
 * @test
 */
public function it_displays_the_dashboard()
{
    $user = UserFactory::new()->createOne();
    $this->auth($user);
    $this->appClient->request('GET', '/'); // <- this requires an auth'd user

    $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful();
    $this->assertSelectorTextContains('[data-test="user-profile"]', $user->getUsername());
}

/**
 * Simulate authentication
 *
 * @param  Proxy  $user
 */
protected function auth(Proxy $user)
{
    $session = self::$container->get('session');
    $firewallName = 'main';

    // **********************************************
    // **********************************************
    // $user = $user->object(); <-- If I uncomment to use the actual User model then auth doesn't work
    // **********************************************
    // **********************************************

    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $firewallName, $user->getRoles());
    $session->set('_security_'.$firewallName, serialize($token));
    $session->save();
    $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
    $this->appClient->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
}
```

The issue I'm encountering is this: If I pass the `Proxy` user to `UsernamePasswordToken` then the token is created successfully and the user is authenticated. However, this causes Twig to not be able to use its magic methods to resolve getter attributes. For example, my Twig template has `{{ user.username }}`, Behind the scenes Twig resolves this to the `getUsername()` method on my `User` instance. But since the `Proxy` class doesn't have such a method, I get this error:

```
Error: Call to undefined method App\Model\User::username()
```

If I modify my template to be `{{ user.getUsername }}` then my test passes.

But, if I pass the `User` class directly to `UsernamePasswordToken` using `$user->object()` then the token is initially created, but then seemingly doesn't exist by the time authentication takes place and my test fails because I'm not authenticated.

If I look at the stacktrace I can see that the User is no longer the User that was used when creating the token and I see the following:

```
/Users/myuser/code/adminapp/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php:84:
class Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AnonymousToken#847 (6) {
  private $secret =>
  string(7) "OxIzLMV"
  private $user =>
  string(5) "anon."
  private $roles =>
  array(0) {
  }
  private $roleNames =>
  array(0) {
  }
  private $authenticated =>
  bool(true)
  private $attributes =>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to pass the actual `User` class using `$user->object()` so that I don't have to manipulate my Twig templates by using the getters directly.

Comment: Hm, have you tried to replace `self::$container->get('session')` to `$this->appClient->getContainer()->get('session')`?

Comment: Also, the problem can be in entityManager that used while creating user entity.

Comment: @EugeneRuban Thanks for the suggestion of using `$this->appClient`. Unfortunately this yields the same result.

Comment: @EugeneRuban Regarding your Entity Manager comment, can you please elaborate?